# jRating stars not showing in Zend Framework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I am using the jRating - jQuery Plugin v2.2(newest version), I can get it to work in html but when I add everything to my ZF project it doesn't work. The star images do not show.. The paths are 100% I have triple checked. I also have a problem with jQuery lightbox plugin's images, the prev, next and close image buttons won't work, is there something I'm missing with ZF jQuery and images?

Here is the ZF version:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >            <title>Clubs - Manchester Nightlife</title>
<link href="/MN/public/css/jRating.jquery.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MN/public/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MN/public/js/jRating.jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="exemple">
    <div class="basic" id="12_1"></div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.basic').jRating();
    });
</script>
</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is the ZF version

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Pluggin jRating : Ajax rating system with jQuery</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jRating.jquery.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="exemple">
<div class="basic" id="4_1"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jRating.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.basic').jRating();
    });
</script>
```

The script tags are in different places due to the way I have added them in the head tag using the ZF way of:

```
$this->headScript()->prependFile($this->baseUrl('/js/jquery.js'));
```

Thanks

Comment: I always thought that a person who is experienced enough to start using ZF knows about **debug** :-S

Comment: "is there something I'm missing with ZF jQuery and images?" --- yes, you're missing what ZF and a plain html page have in common: the resulting html. And in fact your browser doesn't care of what was in the origins - the 30mb php framework or just a static page served as-is.

Comment: the resulting html is the same.. Any help? Possibly?

Comment: if resulting html is the same - then it works the same. If it doesn't work the same - then there is some difference in html and/or js

Comment: are there any other things I need to know about using jQuery in ZF other than the usual stuff, i.e.: adding the head scripts and css the ZF way?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I used ZendX's JQuery library I always have to add the following code to header of my layout

```
<?php echo $this->headLink();
      echo $this->headScript();
      $this->jQuery()->setUiVersion( '1.8.7' )->setVersion( '1.4.4' );
      echo $this->jQuery(); ?>
```

I have no idea why this works, but it does.

Make sure to add the view helper to application.ini

```
resources.view.helperPath.ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper"
```

And then in bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initViewHelpers()
{
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();

    $view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');
    $view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/JQuery', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_JQuery');

    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);

}
```

Comment: It is always a bad idea to advice something that you have no idea about. PS: doubtfully it would help in this case, as long as OP said the generated html is the same

Comment: Looks like you might want to make sure the path to jRating is included in your plugin path as per your error message.